# Automatic running of a method in a class full of non static variables

Tags: java

I have a program that needs a class file written to make it run and I cannot change the original program (a java file).

The java file that i cannot change instantiates a few versions of the class lets say something like this:

```
CrazyClass crazy1 = new CrazyClass();
CrazyClass crazy2 = new CrazyClass();
CrazyClass crazy3 = new CrazyClass();
//more code follows
```

It then sets variables in those newly instantiated classes something like this:

```
crazy1.var1 = 6;
crazy2.var1 = 7;
crazy3.var1 = 8;
//more code follows
```

Later the program actually calls those instantiated classes in a println statement like this:

```
System.out.println(crazy1);
```

and expects a message to pop out..

My question is how do I make this happen? Am I completely off base to think that classes that must be instantiated cannot have return values? I can only think that I need a method inside the class that returns the message and is automatically called, something like main but not static. Am I heading in the right direction here or totally off base? Please advise I have been reading all day and I fear I cannot see the forest for the trees at this point. Im sure its something simple.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: 1. `crazy1..3` are not classes, but instances of classes---so-called **objects**. 2. `System.out.println(crazy1)` doesn't **call** `crazy1`. It calls `println` with `crazy1` as an argument. 3. Classes don't have return values, whether they "must be instantiated" or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to override [`Object.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29).

In the above print-statement, the `println()`-method internally calls the `toString()`-method on the given object. This method can be overwritten to return something meaningful. E.g:

```
@Override
public String toString(){
  return "My var1-field has a value of: "+this.var1;
}
```

Comment: to darn fast! 1+ More specifically to the OP, @dc5553, give the CrazyClass a `public String toString() {/* return info here */}` method that makes sense. If you're using Eclipse or NetBeans there are ways to have the IDE create a first-stab effort that's not too bad.

Comment: Thank you that was the special sauce!